# How to modify style of selected LI

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I am trying to change the color of an LI when I click on it.
this is the code:

```js
todosUl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //get the element that was clicked on
    var elementClicked = event.target;
    //check if the elemenClicked is a Delete button
    if (elementClicked.className === 'completedButton') {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementClicked.parentNode.id);
        var lis = document.getElementById(element.id);
        console.log(lis);
        lis.style.color = "red";
    }
});
```

When i put `console.log(lis)`, the console gives the Li element, so it selects it properly when you click on the element, but it does not change the color of it.

when I inspect the Li, this is what appears:

```
<li class="li-class" id="0">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor0"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton0">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton0">save changes</button></li>
```

Comment: It would seem that your `if` is returning false. Where are you putting the `console.log` you mention?

Comment: i put the console log inside the if, so it is returning true!

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to turn red on click?

Comment: Your logic seems correct. Here's a working plunker http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Sr0h75pEVjXthhTr

Do all elements have `id`s set correctly?

Comment: i want to turn red just the text of the Li

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the clicks on the parent `ul` and if it is the li itself or one of it's children color it:

```js
const ulElement = document.querySelectorAll('ul')[0];
ulElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) { // catch all click event on parent ul
  if (!event.target || !event.target.parentElement) {return} // if the click not on li or one of the child ignore it
  else if (event.target.parentElement.classList.contains('li-class')) { // if clicked element's parent is li with the class
    event.target.parentElement.style.color = 'red';
  } 
  else if (event.target.classList.contains('li-class')) { // if clicked element is li with the class
    event.target.style.color = 'red'
  }
  
}, false);
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="li-class" id="0">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor0"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton0">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton0">save changes</button></li>
<li class="li-class" id="1">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor1"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton1">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton1">save changes</button></li>
<li class="li-class" id="2">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor2"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton2">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton2">save changes</button></li>
</ul>
```

OLD ANSWER:

I guess there are lot of ways achieve this behavior, this solution catchs all clicked events and if it `.li-class` itself, or a child of this class - change the color.

Snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) { // catch all click event on the documnt
  if (!event.target || !event.target.parentElement) {return} // if the click is on the document ignore it
  else if (event.target.parentElement.classList.contains('li-class')) { // if clicked element's parent is li with the class
    event.target.parentElement.style.color = 'red';
  } 
  else if (event.target.classList.contains('li-class')) { // if clicked element is li with the class
    event.target.style.color = 'red'
  }
  
}, false);
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="li-class" id="0">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor0"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton0">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton0">save changes</button></li>
<li class="li-class" id="1">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor1"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton1">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton1">save changes</button></li>
<li class="li-class" id="2">( ) 1<input class="editor" id="editor2"><input type="checkbox" class="completedButton"><button class="deleteButton" id="deleteButton2">X</button><button class="saveButton" id="saveButton2">save changes</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems correct however you might want to consider another approach as shown in the code snippet below:

```js
const todosUl = document.querySelector("ul.todos");

/* Select all li elements of todos ul, and set each up inside of
forEach callback */
todosUl.querySelectorAll("li.li-class").forEach((li) => {

  /* Logic that changes li color when completed checkbox clicked */
  const onClickCompleted = () => {
    li.style.color = "red";
  }

  /* Bind click completed callback logic to the checkbox of this current li element */
  li.querySelector("input.completedButton").addEventListener('click', onClickCompleted);
  
  /* Bind click logic for other buttons of li element
  li.querySelector("button.deleteButton").addEventListener('click', onClickDeleted);
  li.querySelector("button.saveButton").addEventListener('click', onClickSave);
  */
});
```

```html
<ul class="todos">
  <li class="li-class">( ) 1<input class="editor">
    <input type="checkbox" class="completedButton">
    <button class="deleteButton" class="deleteButton">X</button>
    <button class="saveButton" class="saveButton">save changes</button>
  </li>
  <li class="li-class">( ) 2<input class="editor">
    <input type="checkbox" class="completedButton">
    <button class="deleteButton" class="deleteButton">X</button>
    <button class="saveButton" class="saveButton">save changes</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This method takes advantage of document queries that are relative to each `li` element of your list. The benifit of this is that event logic binding is not reliant on specific element id's (ie `deleteButton0`, `editor1`, etc), which tends towards more maintainable code in the long term. Hope that helps!